# Calendar.setTimeInMillis error - why is that?

Tags: java, android, unix-timestamp, android-calendar, java.util.calendar

calendar gets wrong unix time as I got.

```
long millis = 1568814839L;
System.out.println(millis); //1568814839
Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tashkent"));
calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));//839
```

What should I do? Calendar.YEAR should be 2019 with that millis. However, calendar gives me 1970, why?

Comment: That's because 1568814839 is the time in millis but overall it contains a minute, an hour, a day, a month and a year.

Comment: I didn't understand anything

Comment: your 1568814839 is: Wednesday, September 18, 2019 1:53:59 and 839 seconds, so when you `get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)` it will return to you 839

Comment: But Calendar.YEAR returns me 1970 with that millis. Month is 1 and day is 19(839 since 1970 1 1)

Comment: drop the `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tashkent")`

Comment: Nothing changed, still 1970 and 839

Comment: yes because you are not setting the other fields, just the time in millis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to you confusing time in milliseconds and time in seconds. `1568814839L` is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970, but you're treating it as milliseconds.  This is quite easy to check:

```
long millis = 1568814839L;
System.out.println(millis); //1568814839
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tashkent"));
System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis()); //1568820981321
calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));//839
```

This will produce:

```
1568814839
1568820981321
1970
```

As you can see, your number is 3 orders of magnitude off.  Add three 0's to the end of your millis number:

```
long millis = 1568814839000L;
...
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Now you get:

```
1568814839000
1568821211006
2019
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

The modern code would use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Feed your count of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z to the `Instant` class:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1_568_814_839L)
                               .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tashkent"));
    System.out.println(zdt);
    System.out.println("Year: " + zdt.getYear());
    System.out.println("Millisecond of second: "
                        + zdt.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND));
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2019-09-18T18:53:59+05:00[Asia/Tashkent]
> Year: 2019
> Millisecond of second: 0
> ```

As others have said, your number is seconds since the epoch, not milliseconds.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.